# Symbols in right aligned textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, right-align

I have textbox in my web application , which is right aligned . When i type normal charters (such as a, b c ...) it works properly .But if i type a $name  , it appears as name$ . Why is it so .Is there any solution to avoid this  .
I use javascript to set the alignment 
**$("#<%=txtName.ClientID %>").css('direction', 'rtl');**

Comment: "direction" is not the same as "right aligned" (use text-align instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably used the [`dir`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html) attribute/CSS set to `rtl` instead of proper CSS alignment.

The [`dir` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2):

> This attribute specifies the base direction of directionally neutral text (i.e., text that doesn't have inherent directionality as defined in [UNICODE]) in an element's content and attribute values. It also specifies the directionality of tables.

As you can see this is not limited to alignment.

Use CSS alignment/positioning to align HTML controls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have used $("#<%=txtName.ClientID %>").css('direction', 'rtl'); to set the alignment

Comment: @json - Please _edit_ your question to add relevant information. Putting it in comments is not as constructive.